# Thread 1 received signal Sigbart?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Hi i am new to Xcode and I'm making a simple addition app
I just completed it when i got this:

> 2012-07-17 19:06:55.478 Add[3526:fe03] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Result.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x13c7022 0x1558cd6 0x13c6ee1 0x9bf022 0x930f6b 0x930edb 0x94bd50 0x23371a 0x13c8dea 0x13327f1 0x23226e
>   0xd81fc 0xd8779 0xd899b 0x37401 0x37670 0x37836 0x3e72a 0xf596 0x10274
>   0x1f183 0x1fc38 0x13634 0x12b1ef5 0x139b195 0x12ffff2 0x12fe8da
>   0x12fdd84 0x12fdc9b 0xfc65 0x11626 0x1b7d 0x1ae5 0x1) terminate called
>   throwing an exception(lldb)

it automatically took me here to main.m which i will provide the code for:

```
//
//  main.m
//  Add
//
//  Created by Dominic Kynkor on 7/17/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 academy of the holy names. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AdditionAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AdditionAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Does anyone know whats going wrong?

Comment: It also highlighted in green the "return UIApplicationMain" line

Comment: You basically tried to set a property value that wasn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessarily where the error occurred, but it is just showing the app entry point where the uncaught exception has fallen back to. It looks as though somewhere else in your code you might be trying to use an `NSDictionary` incorrectly. The best thing to do is to set a breakpoint where you are calling the `setValue` method and single-step through the code until it throws the exception.

Comment: Better: Set an exception breakpoint. That's easy to do in the breakpoints navigator. Just click the `+` button and select "Add Exception Breakpoint...".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of it. But this error normally appears when you have mis-connections in XIB files. Check your XIB file, ctrl-click the File's Owner, see if any warning there.

Answer (score 0):

What you want the debugger to do is catch the exception at the point it happened, so you can look at the stack trace and see where the setting of Result is happening.

To enable exception breakpoints in Xcode, go to the Breakpoints tab and click the plus sign at the bottom, choose to add an Exception Breakpoint. Take the defaults on the resulting dialog and click Done.

Now your debug session will be far more productive!